# Extend AspNetCore InputTextArea component to add rows

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to extend [InputTextArea](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Components/src/Forms/InputComponents/InputTextArea.cs)  aspnet-core component to add support for rows and use it in razor pages.

The way I was thinking of doing it is to create a new class and inherit from `InputBase<string>` and add a `rows` attribute but I do not know how to implement it further.

```
public class TextAreaWithRows : InputBase<string>
{

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "textarea");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "id", Id);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", BindMethods.GetValue(CurrentValue));
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", BindMethods.SetValueHandler(__value => CurrentValue = __value, CurrentValue));
        builder.AddAttribute(5, "rows", );
        builder.CloseElement();
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Parameter Property for Rows to the class.

```
public class TextAreaWithRows : InputBase<string> {

    //For Attributes
    [Parameter] public int Rows { get; set; }

    //For Events 
    [Parameter] public Action OnInput { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "textarea");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "id", Id);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", BindMethods.GetValue(CurrentValue));
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", BindMethods.SetValueHandler(__value => CurrentValue = __value, CurrentValue));
        builder.AddAttribute(5, "rows", Rows);
        builder.AddAttribute(6, "oninput", EventCallback.Factory.Create<UIEventArgs>(this, OnInput));
        builder.CloseElement();
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```